# How do I create two images in same column within a slickgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, slickgrid

I am attempting to have a select and delete image in one column of my slickgrid and have been unable to do so.  I understand how to do a single image button like so. :

```
var column = {id:delCol, field:'del', name:'Delete', width:250, formatter:buttonFormatter}

//Now define your buttonFormatter function
function buttonFormatter(row,cell,value,columnDef,dataContext){  
    var button = "<input class='del' type='button' id='"+ dataContext.id +"' />";
    //the id is so that you can identify the row when the particular button is clicked
    return button;
    //Now the row will display your button
}
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for that cell should include whatever you need for both images/buttons either as an array or {} (object).

Then create one formatter for when you want both in a cell:

```
// if value is [dataContext.delete.id, dataContext.add.id] for example
function twoButtonFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  var str = ''; // initialize a string

  // First button
  str += "<input class='del' type='button' id='"+ value[0] +"' /> ";

  // second button
  str += "<button data-id='"+value[1]+"' class='add'>Add</button>";

  // return the html string of both buttons
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Works great, oddly enough I tried something like this before and was getting errors.  Must have had something set incorrectly.  Thanks for the code snippet.